# CSS Menu mobile desconfigurado

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Quando o site fica responsivo o menu fica com aquele botão para abrir um menu. O problema que estou passando é a questão do `CSS` dele. Ele deveria ter um estilo, bonitinho, ficar em `block`, só que ele fica dessa maneira:

[image]

Não sei o porque, o código está assim:

```
<div class="col-md-7" id="menu">

              <nav role="navigation" class="navbar">
                <div class="navbar-header navbar-default">
                  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  </button>
                </div>

                <div id="menu-collapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse menu">
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('sobre');?>">Sobre nós</a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('produtos');?>">Produtos</a>
                    <ul>
                    <?php echo dropdown();?>
                    </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('contato');?>">Localização & Contato</a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('orcamento');?>"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i> Orçamento</a></li>
                    <li class="hidden-md hidden-lg"><input type="text" class="form-control search"name="buscar" placeholder="Buscar..."></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>

              </nav>

            </div>
```

**Link do site online:** http://www.servidorcafedigital.com.br/clientes/ktf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Junta isto no teu CSS para mobile:

```css
#menu-collapse { overflow: none; } /* tirar o scroll */
#menu-collapse ul > li {           /* manter tudo à esquerda, um por linha */
    float: left;
    clear: both;
}
```

e tira

```css
#menu ul li:nth-child(1){
    margin-left:0px;
}
```

do `custom.css` (linha 81) para evitar que o `home` esteja desalinhado com os outros.

Comment: deu uma grande melhorada, só que o seguinte... A parametro `#menu-collapse ul > li` deixa o menu `block` quando acessa em desktop. Ele deve ficar `block` só quando for mobile.

Comment: @AlissonAcioli se precisas então podes usar uma media query typo: `@media screen and (max-width: 300px) { regras de CSS aqui }`

Comment: Eu fiz de outra forma que funcionou :) `.navbar-collapse.in{ overflow: hidden !important;} /* tirar o scroll */
.navbar-collapse.in > ul > li {           /* manter tudo à esquerda, um por linha */
    float: left !important;
    clear: both !important;
}`