# Colocar fundo no Toogle Navigation na versão mobile. O menu não está desconfigurado e sim sem fundo!

Tags: html, css, html5, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho um template do qual na versão `mobile` fica como a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso fazer para que o menu fique sobre a logo? Abaixo o código:

```
<div class="navbar-header">
   <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" 
                 data-target=".navbar-collapse" style="z-index: 100000">
   <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   </button>
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html" style="z-index: 0">
      <img src="img/logo.png" alt="Basica" class="img-responsive logoMarca">
   </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [CSS Menu mobile desconfigurado](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/64285/css-menu-mobile-desconfigurado)

Comment: Olá moshMage. Não é duplicata. Observe que o problema dele é diferente do meu. O menu dele fica desconfigurado, no meu fica transparente. Problemas diferentes.

Comment: Cole o código css